# как изменить titlle через vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

при загрузки сайта title меняется

```js
new Vue({
    el: 'title',
    data:{
        title: 'load'
    }
});
```

но потом требуется его изменить еще раз, но он уже не меняется. Как это правильно реализовать?

Comment: Воспользуйтесь компонентом `vue-meta`  там же есть примеры как исползовать в различных ситуациях. 
https://github.com/nuxt/vue-meta

Comment: В момент когда надо менять значение `title`, присвойте `this.title = "new_value"`. А там где надо выводить это значение используйте `{{ title }}`

Comment: `document.title = 'Привет';`

Comment: Не нужно создавать экземпляр приложения для одного тега.